# Bourbon fails when installing in an arbitrary local directory

Tags: rubygems, sass, bourbon

I'm using bourbon in a tornado application. So to install bourbon I wrote this simple make rule:

```
gems:
    export GEM_HOME=./gems; gem install sass bourbon
```

Then when I try to run bourbon I get this:

```
$ ./gems/bin/bourbon
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bourbon' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from ./gems/bin/bourbon:22:in `<main>'
```

sass appears to work fine. I'm not used to work with ruby gems, so I have no clue what is going on.
I apologize if this is a trivial problem.

I posted this same question in [bourbon's github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/602).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. When you install gems, changing the `GEM_HOME` variable (`export GEM_HOME=./gems`) then, every time you want to use the executables installed by the gems, you should previously set the `GEM_HOME` variable the same way you did when installing.